# why does $f(\alpha) $ vanish and $f(\beta)$ don't, eventhough both tend to $0$ in the proof of L'Hospital rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-explanation

there is a part that I don't really understand which is when there is some inequality like $|x_m - x_n |< \epsilon$ and you let $x_m  \to \infty $ without the $x_n$ one example is :

if $a<\alpha <\beta$ and $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x)= \lim_{x \to a^+} g(x)= 0 $ does that mean by taking $(\alpha , \beta) \to a^+ $ then $\frac{f(\beta)-f(\alpha)}{g(\beta)-g(\alpha)} =\frac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)}$

In the proof of L'hopital rule I don't understand how we reached the last step since both $\alpha $ and $\beta$ goes to $a^+$ then why we let   $f(\alpha),g(\alpha)$ vanish and not $g(\beta) ,f(\beta)$ I am really confused here

the theory assert that $\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} =\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$  and since $|\frac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)} -L|< \epsilon $ that means $\beta \to a^+$
[image]

Comment: Nowhere in the proof we have $\beta\to a^+$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think it is implied as the theory assert that $\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} =\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =L$   and since $|\frac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)} -L|< \epsilon $ that means $\beta \to a^+$  as $x \to a^+$

Comment: No that implication is not there and it is not intended. Don't try to overthink and instead focus on what is actually mentioned in the proof. $\beta$ is just any arbitrary number in interval $(a,c]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show: $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists\,\delta>0$ such that $\beta-a<\delta\ \Rightarrow\ \big|f(\beta)/g(\beta)-L\big|<\varepsilon$. The role of $\alpha$ is just a parameter to help prove the implication $\Rightarrow$. In other words, the logic is $\beta$ depends on $\varepsilon$ and $\alpha$ depends on $\beta$.

---

Namely, fix $\varepsilon>0$ first, since $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)/g'(x)=L$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$u-a<\delta\ \Rightarrow\ |f'(u)/g'(u)-L|<\varepsilon.$$

By the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, this implies

$$\beta-a<\delta\ \Rightarrow\ \left|\frac{f(\beta)-f(\alpha)}{g(\beta)-g(\alpha)}-L\right|<\varepsilon\ \ \forall\alpha\in(a,\beta).$$

Note that the above inequality holds for **all** $\alpha\in(a,\beta)$, which means changing $\alpha$ will not affect $\beta$, and therefore we can send $\alpha\to a^+$ such that $f(\alpha)\to0$. This implies

$$\left|\frac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)}-L\right|<\varepsilon,$$

which concludes the $\Rightarrow$ implication.